# Fixed SVG position in scrolling Flex item

Tags: css, svg, flexbox, position, css-position

I found a hacky way to stick a faux SVG shadow to the bottom of a scrolling flex-item.

Some attempts include

- position: absolute, but the SVG ends up at the bottom of the flex container.
- a flex container with position: relative inside the flex item.  The shadow ends up floating in the middle of the container on scroll.
- position: sticky, which works until you get to the bottom of the scroll and the shadow moves up ~4px (which is the translateY).

In the code below, I added a third flex-item, and inserted the SVG into it, then displacing the top position to mimic the shadow at bottom of the above flex-item.

Why not use CSS shadow?  This particular shadow is an inner shadow I could not produce using CSS.  Perhaps you know of a way.

Requirements for this solution

- shadow must remain at bottom of scrolling container
- scrolling container has dynamic height

I welcome ideas that would deliver a cleaner solution.

```js
var box = document.querySelector(".box");
var flexItem = box.querySelector(".toggle--flex");
var flexButton = box.querySelector(".button__toggle--flex");

function toggleFlexDisplay() {
  if (flexItem.style.display === "none") {
    flexItem.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    flexItem.style.display = "none";
  }
}

flexButton.addEventListener("click", toggleFlexDisplay);
```

```css
* { 
  font: 1em/1.3 Lato;
}
.box {
  background: #FCE65F;
  padding: 1em;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
.flex__item {
  background: #F8CC37;
  margin: 0.5em 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
.flex__item--lighter {
  background: #EFEFEF;
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex: 1;
}
.flex__item--shadow {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.spacer {
  height: 30px;
  background: #653533;
}
.shadow {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0.5em 0;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
}
button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
      <div class="flex flex--column">
        <div class="flex__item flex__item--lighter">
          Duis gravida, elit iaculis varius pellentesque, eros dui luctus velit, a bibendum nulla nunc non magna. Cras laoreet, est at dignissim lacinia, mi justo blandit nulla, ut consequat lectus quam eu arcu. Aliquam non lectus sagittis, interdum augue sed,
          tempus elit. Cras ultricies volutpat justo, in porta ante laoreet vitae. Nunc vehicula feugiat rutrum. Nam et elit erat. Suspendisse risus mauris, ornare id posuere et, consectetur vel sem. Duis gravida, elit iaculis varius pellentesque, eros
          dui luctus velit, a bibendum nulla nunc non magna. Cras laoreet, est at dignissim lacinia, mi justo blandit nulla, ut consequat lectus quam eu arcu. Aliquam non lectus sagittis, interdum augue sed, tempus elit. Cras ultricies volutpat justo,
          in porta ante laoreet vitae. Nunc vehicula feugiat rutrum. Nam et elit erat. Suspendisse risus mauris, ornare id posuere et, consectetur vel sem.
        </div>
        <div class="flex__item flex__item--shadow">
          <svg class="shadow" height="18" width="100%">
            <defs>
              <filter id="gauss">
                <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="4" />
              </filter>
            </defs>
            <line x1="0" x2="100%" y1="18" y2="18" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" />
            <rect x="2%" y="7" rx="10" ry="5" width="96%" height="40" fill="red" fill-opacity="0.5" filter="url(#gauss)" /> Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="flex__item toggle--flex" style="display:block; position:relative;">
          <div class="spacer"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="button__toggle--flex">Toggle Flex Item </button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this with multiple CSS inset box shadows. They'll stack on top of each other. The red one will go all the way along the bottom and you can use the white ones to overlap the edges, giving the illusion that the red shadow doesn't go all the way from end to end.

```
box-shadow: 
    inset -25px 8px 8px 1px #EFEFEF, //this stacks on top of the red one
    inset 25px 8px 8px 1px #EFEFEF, //this stacks on top of the red one
    inset 0 -13px 10px 0 rgba(255,0,0,0.5); //bottom shadow
```

Here they are applied to .flex__item--lighter on your original snippet:

```js
var box = document.querySelector(".box");
var flexItem = box.querySelector(".toggle--flex");
var flexButton = box.querySelector(".button__toggle--flex");

function toggleFlexDisplay() {
  if (flexItem.style.display === "none") {
    flexItem.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    flexItem.style.display = "none";
  }
}

flexButton.addEventListener("click", toggleFlexDisplay);
```

```css
* {
  font: 1em/1.3 Lato;
}

.box {
  background: #FCE65F;
  padding: 1em;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.flex__item {
  background: #F8CC37;
  margin: 0.5em 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.flex__item--lighter {
  background: #EFEFEF;
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  box-shadow: inset 10px 20px 30px 5px #fff,
              inset -10px 20px 30px 5px #fff,
              inset 0px -5px 20px 0px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.flex__item--shadow {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.spacer {
  height: 30px;
  background: #653533;
}

.shadow {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}

button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0.5em 0;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
}

button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="flex flex--column">
    <div class="flex__item flex__item--lighter">
      Duis gravida, elit iaculis varius pellentesque, eros dui luctus velit, a bibendum nulla nunc non magna. Cras laoreet, est at dignissim lacinia, mi justo blandit nulla, ut consequat lectus quam eu arcu. Aliquam non lectus sagittis, interdum augue sed,
      tempus elit. Cras ultricies volutpat justo, in porta ante laoreet vitae. Nunc vehicula feugiat rutrum. Nam et elit erat. Suspendisse risus mauris, ornare id posuere et, consectetur vel sem. Duis gravida, elit iaculis varius pellentesque, eros dui
      luctus velit, a bibendum nulla nunc non magna. Cras laoreet, est at dignissim lacinia, mi justo blandit nulla, ut consequat lectus quam eu arcu. Aliquam non lectus sagittis, interdum augue sed, tempus elit. Cras ultricies volutpat justo, in porta
      ante laoreet vitae. Nunc vehicula feugiat rutrum. Nam et elit erat. Suspendisse risus mauris, ornare id posuere et, consectetur vel sem.


    </div>

    <div class="flex__item toggle--flex" style="display:block; position:relative;">
      <div class="spacer"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="button__toggle--flex">Toggle Flex Item </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you.  A couple of things of note: The CSS shadow doesn't have as much control over rounded corners and gets cutoff by the scroll bar track.  https://codepen.io/sandraqu/pen/zWybNL